# Creating an Image annotation tool in vue 3

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuejs3, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a web app that allows users to annotate on images as well as on videos (future scope). I was using fabric.js package. I was also trying to draw with SVG, Now I want to add labels to each annotation. Also want to see them as layers, I'm willing to start from scratch if I get new ideas.

I'm open to suggestion.

Comment: Seeking recommendations for libraries, books, tutorials, etc is *off-topic* on [SO] as it is likely to receive answers based on opinions, rather than facts. Please read [ask]. Use [SO] to ask about specific code you wrote which is supposed to work a certain way and it doesn't. Make sure to include any links to documentation stating your code should work the way you expect to, where appropriate. Last, but not least, consider reading [this particular answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1891677).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use fabric js and just add images and videos with fabrics Image object and then add text boxes with their Textbox object. I think it will be pretty straight forward with fabric.